# How does flatMap manage threads?

Tags: java, project-reactor

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
        .log(null, Level.INFO,true) // line 18
        .flatMap(value -> Mono.just(value.toUpperCase())
                              .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()), 2)
        .log(null, Level.INFO,true) // line 21
        .subscribe();
```

Some of the output:

```
13:03:46 [main] INFO  - | request(2)    Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [main] INFO  - | onNext(a)     Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [main] INFO  - | onNext(b)     Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [elastic-2] INFO  - onNext(A)  Flux.log(App.java:21)
13:03:46 [elastic-2] INFO  - | request(1)   Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [main] INFO  - | onNext(c)     Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [elastic-3] INFO  - onNext(B)  Flux.log(App.java:21)
13:03:46 [elastic-3] INFO  - | request(1)   Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [elastic-2] INFO  - onNext(C)  Flux.log(App.java:21)
13:03:46 [elastic-2] INFO  - | request(1)   Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [main] INFO  - | onComplete()  Flux.log(App.java:18)
13:03:46 [main] INFO  - onComplete()    Flux.log(App.java:21)
```

Questions:

1. Why does `flatMap` ask for 2 elements from the `main` thread and then ask for more elements from the other threads?
2. Why isn't the `subscribe` handled by the `main` thread?

Comment: What's the library you're using (i.e., where do `Flux`, `Mono`, and `Schedulers` come from)? And add applicable version information too.

Comment: Hi Mike, they come from `Reactor` library: http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/ https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core

Comment: I still don't think I understand your question. What do you mean when you say "...and ask for more elements from the other threads?" Could you clarify?

Comment: @Mike I advise you to start reading about reactor here: https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/07/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-i-the-reactive-landscape. My question is related to the second part of this tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why 2 requested from the main thread?

The first `Subscription.request` amount depends on your specified concurrency level, which is `2`. Since you call `.subscribe` in the main thread, the first `prefetch` request will be called exactly on that thread.

Let's take a look at the next schema:

`.subscribe()[Thread main]` -> `FluxLog.source.subscribe()[Tread Main]` -> `FluxFlatMap.source.subscribe()[ThreadMain]` -> `FluxJust.subscriber.onSubscribe()` -> `FluxFlatMap.subscription.request(concurrency)[Thread Main]`

### What happens next?

Then, starting from that point will be hardcore :). Since your inner stream will be subscribed by [`FlatMapInner`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxFlatMap.java#L869) which will observe all signals (onNext, onError, onComplete) on `Scheduler.elastic` (because of your `.publishOn`). In turn, when the inner stream has been completed, the `FlatMapInnner` on its `onComplete` will notify main `FlatMapMain` which is a driver of whole `flatMap` mechanism. Interaction between `FlatMapInner` and `FlatMapMain` is being over [`FlatMapMain.innerComplete`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxFlatMap.java#L826). Since, from the FlatMapMain perspective, internal `FlatMapInner` is playing the role of `Queue`, all elements will be [`drained`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxFlatMap.java#L539). Keep calm, don't panic if you have no idea whata f*** is going on here. All idea of that method is drain data from the inner stream and emit it to downstream, and then request new portion of data to upstream. The thing that you should remember is that `innerComplete` was called from `FlatMapInner.onComplete` which was moved to another Scheduler, so it means that next `Subscription.request` will be called from the thread specified in  `Mono.just(value.toUpperCase()).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())`

So, schematically that process looks like next:

`FluxFlatMap.FlatMapMain.onNext [Thread Main]` -> `Publisher m = mapper(...)` -> `m.subscribe(new FluxFlatMap.FlatMapInner())` -> `FluxFlatMap.FlatMapInner.onNext("a") [Thread Elastic N]` -> `LambdaSubscriber.onNext("c") [Thread Elastic N]` -> `FluxFlatMap.FlatMapInner.onComplete() [Thread Elastic N]` -> `FluxFlatMap.FlatMapMain.drainLoop() [Thread Elastic N]` -> `FluxFlatMap.FlatMapMain.drainLoop() [Thread Elastic N] { ... subscription.request(amountOfCompletedInners)` -> `FlatMap.FlatMapMain.onNext() [Thread Elastic N]` -> .... `LambdaSubscriber.onNext("c") [Thread Elastic N]` -> ....

Thus, you will see the first request(2) on main and then request(1) from elastic (because one inner has been completed so FlatMap will request another 1 element from upstream to satisfy the demand of concurrency).

Comment: I'm new to Spring Reactive programming. You sound like you really know your stuff. But did you actually answer his questions 1 and 2 here?

Comment: @OlehDokuka your explanation is clear. The only thing I didn't understand is why you wrote: `concurrencyLevel - amountOfCompletedInners = 1` ? How it relate to your answer?

Comment: @Mike He did answer both my questions. Thanks.

Comment: @stav-alfi great! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The internal mechanism is next - when flatted inner Stream has been completed, it notifies `FlatMap` about that. In turn, `FlatMap` run internal mechanism which is trying to verify whether another flatted streams have also been completed. In turn, on each completed inner streams (amount of parallel inners streams specified by your second parameter which is 2) `FlatMap` count them, and tries to request exactly that count to upstream to satisfy requested concurrency. So you are right, it is incorrect formula, sorry for that, I will fix it

Comment: I have added schematic explanation to my answer, hope it helps